# Windows 7 amd64 guest in kvm does not have sound

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, virtual-machine, audio, linux-kvm

my host system is gentoo amd64, guest system is Windows 7 amd64. the guest system can work, except it does not have sound. I start kvm with -soundhw ac97, QEMU_AUDIO_DRV='alsa', and after I get into the guest system, I can see a 'Multimedia Audio Controller' in the device manager. but Windows 7 cannot find the driver for it. I searched the network for a long time, and I cannot find a driver for Intel ac97 for Windows 7 amd64.

I also tried -soundhw sb16, es1370, none of them work.

Comment: +1 Good question. I was just about to start searching for an answer to this till I stumbled across your question. The only suggestion I'd make is to add the virtual-machine tag since KVM is commonly confused with the KVM hardware. You could also remove the gentoo tag since the issue isn't gentoo specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to answer to my own question. I just found out that Windows 7 x86 guest in kvm with -soundhw ac97 can have sound. I guess we really do not have a driver for that kvm virtual audio device in Windows 7 amd64. so, I think this is as far as I can go. Windows 7 amd64 guest in kvm is **DEAF**...

Answer (score 1):

In late 2010/early 2011 the 'hda' driver was added to qemu-kvm. Libvirt knows it as ich6. That driver is supported out of the box by Windows 7 amd64.